# Get color array with alpha for an image in java

Tags: java, alpha, png

I can get the pixel array like this:

```
int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
```

But it ignores the alpha channel, I only get the rgb (I'm reading a PNG image). How can I get the alpha channel too?

Answer (score 1):

The `getRGB()` method picks all channels, even alpha. You can extract color and alpha channels with something like:

```
Color col = new Color(pixels[pixelIndex]);

System.out.println(col.getRed());
System.out.println(col.getGreen());
System.out.println(col.getBlue());
System.out.println(col.getAlpha());
```

Depending on the image format (ABGR, ARGB), retrievieng specific channel requires some bit shift operation, and applying a mask to it. To get alpha manually, you could do `(pixels[pixelIndex] >> 24) & 0xFF`

Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html for additional info about image types and methods behaviour.